# How do I access application.yml Spring Properties from the BoostrapRegistryInitializer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-configuration

I have the following to initialize a static client...

```java
public class Boostrap implements BootstrapRegistryInitializer {

    @Override
    public void initialize(BootstrapRegistry registry) {
        // TODO: Get the username from properties
        String username = "MyUser";
        registry.register(
            AwsParameterStoreClientCustomizer.class,
            context -> new ParameterStoreClientCustomizer(username)
        );
        registry.register(BootstrapItem.class, context -> new BootstrapItem("Test 123"));
    }
}
```

I would like to get `username` from `myProps.username` so my application.yml file will look like this...

```yaml
myProps:
  username: Test345
```

I want to use the application.yml instead of the bootstrap.yml because I would like to share these properties between the bootstrap and application contexts (IE. 1 place instead of 2).

What is the proper way to access the application yaml property from the BootstrapRegistryInitializer?

Comment: I don't know if that is possible at all, tbh, but what is your point with "I would like to share these properties between the bootstrap and application contexts"? Can you expand on why you need that?

Comment: I think the context is not fully built yet so you may be right let me try as a env var